# How can I add a scroll to top animation to each closed accordion tab in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make an accordion where when you click to close the accordtion (its open by default), the main closed accordion is scrolled to the top of the page, making it to the top of the page and the next open accordion is the focial point. So far, I can get the accordion to close and scroll to the top, but all of them do it too, so it just scrolls all the way down to the bottom of the page.

An Example: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNxvS.jpg)

What I've done so far: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1hW4.jpg)

I've tried react-scroll-to-component, scroll-to and a few others

```
scrollToTop = () => {
    let scroller = scrollToComponent(this.index, {
      offset: 0,
      align: "top",
      duration: 1000,
      ease: "inExpo"
    });

    scroller.on("end", () => console.log("Scrolling End!"));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='news'>
        {this.state.news.map((newbie, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className='news_info' id={`news_info-${index}`}>
              <Accordion defaultActiveKey={index}>
                <Card>
                  <Card.Header>
                    <p>{newbie.title}</p>
                    <Accordion.Toggle
                      as={Button}
                      variant='link'
                      eventKey={index}
                      onClick={this.scrollToTop}
                    >
                      +
                    </Accordion.Toggle>
                  </Card.Header>
                  <Accordion.Collapse
                    eventKey={index}
                    ref={section => {
                      this.index = section;
                    }}
                  >
                    <Card.Body>
                      <img src={newbie.image} />
                      <p>{newbie.details}</p>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
              </Accordion>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mel, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is, you are setting the same `ref` for every `collapsiable`. You need to provide different `ref` using `index` of your `map`.

Your code should look something like this,

```
scrollToTop = (index) => {
    let scroller = scrollToComponent(this['section-'+index], {  //use passed index to scroll exact collapsiable
      offset: 0,
      align: "top",
      duration: 1000,
      ease: "inExpo"
    });

    scroller.on("end", () => console.log("Scrolling End!"));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='news'>
        {this.state.news.map((newbie, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className='news_info' id={`news_info-${index}`}>
              <Accordion defaultActiveKey={index}>
                <Card>
                  <Card.Header>
                    <p>{newbie.title}</p>
                    <Accordion.Toggle
                      as={Button}
                      variant='link'
                      eventKey={index}
                      onClick={() => this.scrollToTop(index)} //pass index here
                    >
                      +
                    </Accordion.Toggle>
                  </Card.Header>
                  <Accordion.Collapse
                    eventKey={index}
                    ref={section => {
                      this['section-'+index] = section;    //dynamic ref
                    }}
                  >
                    <Card.Body>
                      <img src={newbie.image} />
                      <p>{newbie.details}</p>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
              </Accordion>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this did the trick! I was trying to do something like this as you can see in some of my code. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!